# Generate an Audio waveform in Groovy

Tags: grails, audio, groovy, waveform

Is there a way to generate an audio waveform using Groovy? or are there any third party libraries that allows you to generate audio waveforms using groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and play a waveform using java audio like so ([converted from the java here](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/java-sound-generate-play-sine-wave.html)):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*

byte[] wavform( int freq, int seconds, int sampleRate ) {
  byte[] ret = new byte[ seconds * sampleRate ]
  ret.length.times { idx ->
    ret[ idx ] = (byte)( Math.sin( ( 2.0 * Math.PI * idx ) / ( sampleRate / freq ) ) * 127 ) 
  }
  ret
}

int sampleRate = 8000
new AudioFormat( sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true ).with { af ->
  AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine( af ).with { line ->
    line.open( af )
    line.start()
    wavform( 200, 1, sampleRate ).with { byte[] wav ->
      line.write( wav, 0, wav.length )
    }
    line.drain()
    line.close()
  }
}
```

However, as you've tagged this question <kbd>grails</kbd>, I assume you don't want to play it?